# C Get a string from a file

Tags: c, fread, fseek, fputs

I want to get 2 variable strings of fixed length (10chars and 32chars) from a file and save them as variables to pass off later in my program and write them to a new file. I can write the data to a new file  from user input but I can't seem to figure how to locate the data and store it for use so a user won't have to manually input 42 chars and risk error. The strings will vary in content and may vary in position in the file but will always come after a constant string "Serial Number =" for example. What if there is a known offset location where the stings start, can this make it easier? I was thinking fget or fread... But I can't get a working example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)

{
FILE *f;
FILE * pFile;
char sn[11];
char uuid[33];

  if (f = fopen("test.txt", "rt"))
  {
    fseek (f,443,SEEK_SET);  //file offset location to begin read
    fread(uuid, 1, 32, f);   //Read the data of 32 chars
    uuid[32] = 0;
    fseek (f,501,SEEK_SET);  //file offset location to begin read
    fread(sn, 1, 10, f);     //Read the data of 10 chars
    sn[10] = 0;
    fclose(f);  //Close our file
    printf("The 32 character UUID:\n%s\n", uuid);  //Show read/extracted Data
    printf("The 10 character SN:\n%s\n", sn);      //Show read/extracted Data

    pFile = fopen ("testfile.exe","r+b");   //Open binary file to inject data

    fseek (pFile,24523,SEEK_SET);    //1st file offset location to begin write
    fputs (sn,pFile);                //Write our data!

    fseek (pFile,24582,SEEK_SET);    //2nd file offset location to begin write
    fputs (uuid,pFile);              //Write our data!

    fseek (pFile,24889,SEEK_SET);    //3rd file offset location to begin write
    fputs (uuid,pFile);              //Write our data!

    fclose(pFile);                  //Close our file

    printf ("Finished\n");
    }
return(0);
}
```

I worked and read up on it all weekend, I now get the desired results, reading data from one file and injecting into another.  Although this works, It may not be the best method.  I apologize in advance for the mis tagged post, I submitted from my mobile and didnt have access to my source.  Thanks for all the input.  I welcome more.  I tried to document as I understood what I was doing.

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: I have added my solution

Answer (score 0):

you can use fgetc and count each char in one string and say if c==" " means another word and reset your count.

Comment: Given my solution, how would you implement your suggestion?  Im just looking to learn other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Though your solution works, you may find it practical not having to predetermine the offsets in `"test.txt"` where the strings start, but rather letting the program search for them, e. g. using

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void find(FILE *f, const char *s)
{   // searches stream f for string s, positions f after s
    int c;
    long offset;
    const char *cp;
    for (; ; )
    for (offset = ftell(f), cp = s; ; ) // save starting point
        if (!*cp) return;   // at end of search string - found
        else
        if ((c = fgetc(f)) == *cp) ++cp;    // character match
        else
        if (c == EOF) printf("\"%s\" not found\n", s), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        else
        if (cp > s) { fseek(f, offset, SEEK_SET), fgetc(f); break; }
}
```

and replacing

```
    fseek (f,443,SEEK_SET);  //file offset location to begin read
```

and

```
    fseek (f,501,SEEK_SET);  //file offset location to begin read
```

with

```
    find(f, "UUID =");          // really no space after "="?
```

and

```
    find(f, "Serial Number ="); // really no space after "="?
```

respectively.